# How to post additional data within the scope of angular-payments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to build a donation form using [angular-payments](https://github.com/laurihy/angular-payments) and sending the data to an Expressjs server.

Currently I'm having trouble getting my form to post data other than the data that angular-payments sends. How can a post data that's not part of the angular-payments scope using the same controller?

Here is my Angular script:

```
angular.module('donate', ['angularPayments'])

function DonateCtrl($scope, $http) {

  $scope.handleStripe = function(status, response){
    console.log('response', status, response);
    if(response.error) {
      console.log('error');
      // there was an error. Fix it.
    } else {
      // got stripe token, now charge it or smt
      console.log('no error');

      var token = response.id;
      console.log(token);
      return $http.post('http://localhost:8181/api/payments', response)

    }
  }

};
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<form stripe-form="handleStripe" name="donateForm">

  <h3>Credit Card Details</h3>

    <label for="">Card number</label>
    <input type="text" name="number" ng-model="number" payments-validate="card" payments-format="card" payments-type-model="type" ng-class="donateForm.number.$card.type" placeholder="4500 0000 0000 0000" />

    <label for="">Expiry</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="expiry" payments-validate="expiry" payments-format="expiry" placeholder="01 / 99" />

    <label for="">CVC</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="cvc" payments-validate="cvc" payments-format="cvc" payments-type-model="type" placeholder="123" />

  <h3>Donor Details</h3>

    <label for="name">Name on card </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" placeholder="John Smith">

    <label for="address">Street Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="address" ng-model="addressLine1" placeholder="123 Any Street" required/>

    <input type="text" name="city" ng-model="addressCity" placeholder="Anytown" required />
    <input type="text" name="province" ng-model="addressState" placeholder="Any Province" ng-required="addressCountry == 'Canada' || addressCountry == 'United States'" />

    <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country" name="country" ng-model="addressCountry" required>
      {% include 'includes/countryselect' %}
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="postcode" ng-model="addressZip" placeholder="A1B 2C3" ng-required="addressCountry == 'Canada' || addressCountry == 'United States'" />

    <div ng-show="donateForm.addressLine1.$pristine && donateForm.addressLine1.$invalid || donateForm.addressCity.$pristine && donateForm.addressCity.$invalid || donateForm.addressState.$pristine && donateForm.addressState.$invalid || addressCountry.$pristine && addressCountry.$invalid || donateForm.addressZip.$pristine && donateForm.addressZip.$invalid" class="help-block">Enter your full home address.</div>

    <label for="phone">Phone Number <small>(include country &amp; area code)</small></label>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" ng-model="phone" placeholder="+1 204-555-5555" required />
    <div ng-show="donateForm.phone.$invalid && donateForm.phone.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter your phone number.</div>


    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" placeholder="johnsmith@email.com" required />
    <div ng-show="donateForm.email.$invalid && donateForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter your email address.</div>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Save yourself a lot of work by making all `ng-model` point to one object (which is angular best practice anyway ..always have a dot in ng-model) and would be a simple matter of extending stripe response with your model object

Comment: @charlietfl: I think I partially understand. Could you possibly give me an example? I'm not entirely sure how to bind the model for the Stripe data as well as the other data to the http post function.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this directive but assume that you are only posting the stripe response to server. What I am getting at is something like `var postData = angular.extend(stripeResponse, formModelObject)`. when the form is all one object like `<input ng-model="scopeFormObject.fieldName">` then using `extend` is very simple rather than having all sorts of individual ng-model variables

Comment: @charlietfl: sort of. I'm actually needing to post the Stripe response [token], AS WELL as a separate response containing email address and phone number, as well as frequency. Both objects need to be sent to the server.

Comment: right, that's why you use `extend` which merges objects

Answer (score 0):

When you say post additional data, do you mean send data with the POST request?

This is how I do it as an example:

```
$http({
    url: 'http://localhost:8181/api/payments',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
         key: value,
         key2: value
    }).success(function(data) {
          // If successful
    }).error(function(data) {
          // If error
          return data.message;
    });
```